# Success message in popup

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, popup, success-message

I have a frontend form in my custom module. On submitting the form,I want to display the success message in a popup with some custom content. How is it possible? Please help.

This is my controller.

```
public function formAction()
{
    if ($this->getRequest()->getPost()){
    //My Action
    // Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your Request has been sent');
    $this->_redirect("*/");
}
```

This is my phtml

```
<form id="test_sample_form" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('module/controller/action') ?>">
    <fieldset class="group-select">Test Fields</fieldset>
</form>
```

I want to display the success message in a popup. Please help.

Comment: write add success message and call in popup block

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understood. Could you please explain.

Comment: i will provide code

Comment: @Rama Chandran Is there any upadate?

Comment: I am checking code.not success

Comment: No luck. :( . one question you display form in poupop am i right?

Comment: No. Form is not displayed in popup.

Comment: Is there any hope??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61534/discussion-between-v-p-and-rama-chandran).

Answer (score 1):

Submit the form via ajax

Use this script in your phtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callAjax(){ 
     jQuery.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('module/ctrlr/action'); ?>",
        data    : jQuery('#test_sample_form').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function (data) {
            callpopup();
            document.getElementById("test_sample_form").reset();           
        },
    });
}
function callpopup(){ 
    jQuery.fancybox(
        '<p>Content!!!!!</p></br>',
        {
            padding:15,
            closeBtn:true
        }
    );
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Submit the form via ajax

```
        $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            // decode JSON data and load message in popup
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('An error occurred.');
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
```

On the controller side return the value in JSON format, something like below

```
echo  '{"status":"true","message":"YOUR MESSAGE"}';
```

Comment: I have changed the form submission using ajax. But how is it possible to display the popup on ajax success.This is my script. complete: function(response) { alert("success"); jQuery.fancybox({ maxWidth : 450, maxHeight : 350, fitToView : false, width : '70%', height : '70%', autoSize : false, }); },          alert("success") is working. But popup is not loading. Please help.

Comment: You need to trigger fancybox , check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13452197/jquery-fancybox-trigger

Answer (score 0):

like this you can delete everything in popup and then show success content in the same popup

```
 if ($(this).validation('isValid')) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr('action'),
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    dataType: 'html',
                    type: 'POST',
                    showLoader: true,

                    /**
                     * Success function
                     */
                    success: function () {
                        $('#form-div-element').remove();
                        $('#devnewsletter-validate-detail').html(contentOptions.success);
                    }
                });
            }
```

I take successContent from admin page so for me its like

```
contentOptions = {
                success: this.options.successContent
            };
```

I am using popup widget.